# "Function split() is deprecated" error Using DIGG DIGG in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been using [Digg Digg](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/digg-digg/) for while, once I deployed my wordpress blog I started getting the following error:

```
Function split() is deprecated in /../../dd-manual.php on line 385
```

I am using the manual implementation of the code blocks.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

you should use [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). change the following lines:

```
from 385: $link = split(DD_DASH,$postlink);
to   385: $link = explode(DD_DASH,$postlink);
```

Comment: Ah interesting, whats the reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

Online, I found answers like: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/function-split-is-deprecated-how-to-fix-my-code-930614.html they suggested removing the prompt function from the base. I didn't like that solution.

Using preg_split fixes the issue, just replace the following lines:

```
from 385: $link = split(DD_DASH,$postlink);
to   385: $link = preg_split("/{DD_DASH}/",$postlink);
```

Worked for me, if this is the